# Agora io - Webcam light does not switch off even calling .close() method

Tags: reactjs, next.js, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I'm integrating Agora io with a Medical web app build with nextjs and one thing I need to do is to turn off webcam light after video call ended. I tryed to use several ways of creating video tracks but none achived my needs:

- Create by createMicrophoneAndCameraTracks from agora-rtc-react
- Create by createCameraVideoTrack from agora-rtc-react
- Create by AgoraRTC.createCameraVideoTrack from agora-rtc-sdk-ng
- Create by AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAndCameraTracks from agora-rtc-sdk-ng
- Create by AgoraRTC.createCustomVideoTrack from agora-rtc-sdk-ng
  For all of then the close() method seems to do not stop getting camera resources although it successfully triggers "user-unpublished". Could someone give me an example of how to solve this problem? I read AgoraIO docs, it says that with close() method the behavior I expect should happen  but I never happens.

Attempts detailed in previous item

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.